# How do I create beautiful HTML5 webpages

Tags: html

I do server-side and client-side developments pretty well , however, my designs are apparently not catchy enough. Is there anything I need to know to assist me do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. This site is considered a Q&A for clear questions rather than asking for subjective advice to improve something. Please rephrase your question in a way that asks a specific question that can be answered objectively or consult other forums that may help you better.

Comment: Please be more specific on what you need!

Comment: Hi Pandey, I really want to know how best to create images and combine colours to make my design catchy. Most times I get cases of images being blurry or overstretched or colours not balanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plugins like Bootstrap and skeleton and design platforms like SqaureSpace. There are many jquery stuff and many libraries out there  it depends on what you want to build and use jquery and css. That will make your website responsive and beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap,bootswatch and get aware of css,jquery
they can be learnt in a day and sites having catchy UI can be created

Comment: for further enquiry leave a comment